# Generar PDF en los ejecutables compilados con pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, fpdf, pyinstaller

Cuando creo el ejecutable con pyinstaller no me genera el archivo PDF utilizando fpdf, la aplicación funciona bien cuando se ejecuta el .pyw

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Recordá que el directorio de trabajo NO SIEMPRE coincide con el directorio del script/exe (esto pasa en los exes de pyinstaller). Por ejemplo, si tu pdf se guarda en "carpeta/hola.pdf", el verdadero directorio termina siendo "c:/directorio/de/trabajo/carpeta/hola.pdf". En conclusión, es probable que el pdf se esté guardando, pero no donde pensás. Deberás usar rutas absolutas o cambiar el directorio de trabajo en "tiempo de ejecución". En ambos casos sys.argv[0] siempre representa la ubicación del script/exe, independiente del directorio de trabajo.

Comment: Si no es eso, podrías mostrarnos un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder ver el error y hacer pruebas por favor?

Comment: Gracias, por su atención, he buscado en toda la PC, no se genera el .PDF

Comment: Pido perdón, el problema era tan simple como ridículo, no tenía las carpetas en dist, con las imágenes que utiliza el PDF,